# OOP class design in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I have simple question about class design in C++.

Lets assume we have the following class:

```
class DataBase
{
    public:
        DataBase();


        void addEntry(const std::string& key, double value);
        double getEntry(const std::string& key);

    protected:
        std::map<std::string, double> table;
};
```

There is another class which holds a pointer to an instance of `DataBase` class:

```
class SomeClass
{
    protected:
        DataBase *someDataBase;
};
```

Here I get confused, as two options come to my mind:

1. Each instance of `SomeClass` will have a database of its own. In the sense that only the data added by this instance will be present in this database (dedicated databases).
2. Each instance of `SomeClass` will be referring to a central database. Data added by any of the instances of `SomeClass` will be in one single database (a global database).

**Question:**

- What is the name of the aforementioned concepts in OOP?
- How each of the aforementioned approaches can be achieved in C++

Comment: When a SomeClass object adds to its own database, are you wanting that same addition to the central Database object as well?

Comment: nope, I want to consider them separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the topic of ownership in C++. When I say ownership, I mean who is responsible for managing the memory that holds the object.

In your first example each `SomeClass` *could* own its own `DataBase`.

```
class SomeClass
{
    private DataBase *db;
    public SomeClass();
    public SomeClass(DataBase* db);
    public ~SomeClass();
}

SomeClass::SomeClass()
{
    this.db = new DataBase();
}    

SomeClass::SomeClass(DataBase* db)
{
    this.db = db;
}

SomeClass::~SomeClass()
{
    delete this.db;
}
```

This `SomeClass` either takes ownership of the DataBase given to it or creates its own (practically you usually do one or the other). This means you can pass in a `DataBase` object (using a concept known as dependency injection):

```
DataBase *db = new DataBase();
SomeClass sc(db);
sc.doSomeStuffWithDB();
```

or just let the class create the `DataBase` object:

```
SomeClass sc();
sc.doSomeStuffWithDB();
```

In the above example you don't have to worry about disposal of the `DataBase` objects, knowing that `SomeClass` should take care of disposal in its destructor.

In the other scenario you could share a `DataBase` without having it be disposed of by your `SomeClass` (whether it's global or not is irrelevant).

```
class SomeClass
{
    private DataBase *db;
    public SomeClass(DataBase* db);
}

SomeClass::SomeClass(DataBase* db)
{
    this.db = db;
}
```

Here we could pass multiple `SomeClass` objects the same `DataBase` and not have to worry about them being disposed of by any of the objects.

```
DataBase *db = new DataBase();
SomeClass *sc1 = new SomeClass(db);
SomeClass *sc2 = new SomeClass(db);
sc1.doSomeStuffWithDB();
delete sc1;
sc2.doSomeStuffWithDB();
delete sc2;
delete db;
```

In this scenario we were able to reuse the `DataBase` object before disposing of it external to our `SomeClass` objects. Practically speaking, this disposal could be managed by another class like `DataBaseStore`, allowing you to have a reliable way to handle and reuse `DataBase` objects.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Composition](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/102-composition/)
2. [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

With Composition you can just have the `DataBase` as a member:

```
class SomeClass
{
    protected:
        DataBase someDataBase;
};
```

With Dependency injection you basically give `SomeClass` a pointer to your shared `DataBase` and `SomeClass` saves a pointer to it. Be careful if you have a multithreaded application, you need to protect writing to the database and maybe reading as well.

```
class SomeClass
{
    public:
    SomeClass(DataBase* db) : someDataBase(db) {}

    protected:
        DataBase* someDataBase;
};
```

How you crate and where you store the shared `DataBase` is up to you.

Comment: so the my code above represents _Dependency Injection_?

Comment: @cross In a way yes. In general Dependency injection is pattern where you dont hard code dependencies into a class, but you "inject" them at construction. I am no expert on that matter, so I suggest you google for more information on Dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

Concept n°1 is composition. The `Database` is part of the `SomeClass`.
Concept n°2 doesn't have a name as far as I know.

#### Implementing concept n°1 :

This is actually pretty straightworward : give `SomeClass` a member of type `Database`.

```
class SomeClass
{
    protected:
        DataBase someDataBase;
};
```

If you need pointers (e.g for polymorphism), use a `std::unique_ptr` :

```
class SomeClass
{
    protected:
        std::unique_ptr<DataBase> someDataBase;
};
```

#### Implementing concept n°2 :

This depends on the rest of the program. If you can, the simplest way is to have a static `Database` member inside `SomeClass` :

```
class SomeClass
{
    protected:
        static DataBase someDataBase;
// or   static std::unique_ptr<DataBase> someDataBase;
};
```

If `Database` can't be statically initialized, or if you don't want *all* of the `SomeClass`es to share the same `Database`, you can make use of the object factory pattern :

```
class SomeClassFactory {
        // Constructors, etc

        SomeClass createSomeClass(/* args */) {
            return SomeClass(_database, /* args */);
        }

    private:
        Database _database;
// or   std::unique_ptr<Database> _database;
};

class SomeClass {
        friend class SomeClassFactory;

        // Private, only the factory can create SomeClass'es
        SomeClass(Database &database, /* args */)
        : database(database) {}

    protected:
        Database &database;
};
```

Then all `SomeClass`es created by the same factory will share the same `Database`.

Answer (score 0):

1 is object composition.

2 needs another Database* declaration in SomeClass declaration, and both pointers must be initialized.

Comment: the OOP concept is known as object composition, thanks i just couldn't remember the name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the concept itself has a name, but the members are referred to as **static** or **non-static**.
Your *1.* would be **non-static** and your *2.* would be **static**.

As for how to implement this, you seem to know how to go about the non-static variant, and for the static one, just use the `static` keyword in the member declaration:

```
class SomeClass
{
    protected:
        static DataBase *someDataBase;
};
```

Static members can be accessed with `::`, like `SomeClass::someDataBase`.

Initializing static members in C++ is not that straightforward though, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3536372/2302862).

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: 2. does not need a static member. That would just be one of the possible implementations and I don't think it would be considered a good implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I will address both of your options:

1. You have that with your current setup. Each instance of `SomeClass` will have a pointer to a `DataBase` class.
2. In order to achieve this, you have to take `DataBase` out of your `SomeClass`, since `SomeClass` no longer owns the database. You will utilize the singleton design pattern for your `DataBase` class to say "there is only one instance of this class at any one time".

To do that, you will write your database class like so:

```
class DataBase
{
    public:
        DataBase();
        static Database * instance(); // This is the function that is used to get the global database for use.

        void addEntry(const std::string& key, double value);
        double getEntry(const std::string& key);

    protected:
        std::map<std::string, double> table;
    private:
        static DataBase * pDataBase;
};
```

To implement the `instance()` method:

```
static DataBase * DataBase::instance()
{
    if (!pDataBase)
        pDataBase = new DataBase();

    return pDataBase;
}
```

If you would like more information on singletons, read to your heart's content [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton).